# Dragon Curve in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, graphics, fractals

I've been thinking about making a program which would have me input a number and then calculate and display a dragon curve of the iteration of this number. Honestly, I do not know how to even begin tackle this, neither do I know how to make this as elegant and effective as possible. I'd like the curve that would be shown in the program to be savable too (I don't know how to do that either).

---

I know how to fundamentally create a dragon curve, or Heighway dragon as it is sometimes called. One way is as follows.

> Starting from a base segment, replace each segment by 2 segments with a right angle and with a rotation of 45° alternatively to the right and to the left.

Another way is considering a Lindenmayer system with

- angle 90°
- initial string *FX*
- string rewriting rules:

  - *X ↦ X+YF+*
  - *Y ↦ −FX−Y*

Yet another way to create the dragon curve is considering the *turns* the curve makes. For the first few iterations, the sequence of right (R) and left (L) turns is a s follows:

> 1st iteration: R
>   2nd iteration: RRL
>   3rd iteration: RRLRRLL
>   4th iteration: RRLRRLLRRRLLRLL

This suggests the following pattern: each iteration is formed by taking the previous iteration, adding an R at the end, and then taking the original iteration again, flipping it retrograde, swapping each letter and adding the result after the R.

For more information about how to create the dragon curve or about the dragon curve itself, please consider [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve).

---

What I am asking for is a program in Cocoa that would ask me for an iteration, calculate and display the curve for me, and then allow me to save this curve as an image (preferably JPEG, but that doesn't matter).

Thanks in advance.

---

I found [this site](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) which lists several ways in several programming languages but I cannot seem to find any way to do this in Cocoa programming.

Comment: The http://rosettacode.org site you've linked to has 50+ sample implementations - yet *you can't use a single one* as a starting point for your Cocoa version..?

Comment: @cacau I am quite a novice at programming in Cocoa and do not know how to use other program languages' versions as starting points.